# Как считать данные из текстового файла в массив?

Tags: java

Добрый день.
Сейчас имеется массив папок исходников:

```
Path[] paths = new Path[4];
paths[0] = Paths.get("\\\\komp\\D$\\logs");
paths[1] = Paths.get("\\\\komp\\D$\\logs2");
paths[2] = Paths.get("\\\\komp\\D$\\logs3");
paths[3] = Paths.get("\\\\komp\\D$\\logs4");
```

и одна папка получатель:

```
Path target = Paths.get("D:\\MyLogs\\");
```

Есть файл Setting.txt, где содержаться эти пути построчно:

```
\\\\komp\\D$\\logs
\\\\komp\\D$\\logs2
\\\\komp\\D$\\logs3
\\\\komp\\D$\\logs4
D:\\MyLogs
```

Прошу показать, как сделать чтение этих строк из файла и подставить в мой код, что бы было что-то вроде:

```
Path[] paths = new Path[4];
paths[0] = Paths.get("Первая строка из файла Setting.txt");
paths[1] = Paths.get("Вторая строка из файла Setting.txt");
paths[2] = Paths.get("Третья строка из файла Setting.txt");
paths[3] = Paths.get("Четвёртая строка из файла Setting.txt");
```

и одна папка получатель:

```
Path target = Paths.get("Пятая строка из файла Setting.txt");
```

Comment: Нужно считать одну строку из файла, затем повторить пять раз. Можете объяснить что именно у Вас не получается?

Comment: Всё просто - я не знаю, как это делается.

Comment: Понятно, просто здесь несколько вопросов с каждым из которых проще разобраться отдельно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно просто считать файл построчно. Вот как можно реализовать:

```
// метод возвращает строки из файла в массиве String[]
// fileName - имя файла
// linesAmount - кол-во. строк, которые необходимо считать из файла (в вашем случае - 5)
public String[] getLinesFromFile(String fileName, int linesAmount) {
    String[] lines = new String[linesAmount];

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), Charset.forName("КОДИРОВКА_ВАШЕГО_ФАЙЛА")))) {

        String line;
        int i = 0;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && i < linesAmount) {
            lines[i++] = line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return lines;
}
```

Теперь в вашем коде:

```
String[] lines = getLinesFromFile("Setting.txt", 5);

Path[] paths = new Path[4];
paths[0] = Paths.get(lines[0]);
paths[1] = Paths.get(lines[1]);
paths[2] = Paths.get(lines[2]);
paths[3] = Paths.get(lines[3]);

Path target = Paths.get(lines[4]);
```

Comment: Всё время ругается на строку:
new FileInputStream(fileName),
      Честно говоря и сам не понимаю, что за "FileInputStream", но идея просит "закрыть" его.

Comment: @Alex, по поводу `FileInputStream` - это поток ввода файла. Потоки ввода вывода - отдельная тема, с которой я думаю, лучше разобраться отдельно. Тем не менее, код рабочий, только что протестировал. Я думаю, проблема в Language level вашего проекта в IDEA. Если вы опишите ошибку подробнее, я смогу подсказать вам решение.

Comment: Просто new FileInputStream(fileName) подчёркнуто красным, при наведении написано:  
Clouse this "FileInputStream".

Comment: @Alex, посмотрите в IDEA -> File -> Project Structure -> Project -> Project language level. У вас должно быть выбрано значение не ниже 7.

Comment: Указано: SDK default (8 - Lambdas, type annotations etc.)

Comment: @Alex, хм, интересно. Могу я посмотреть весь код целиком? Если не сложно, сделайте UPDATE вашего вопроса.

Comment: Попробовал на другой машине - работает корректно. Спасибо большое за ответ и дальнейшую поддержку кода.

Answer (score 0):

я так понял тебе надо прочитать и записать их в массив? вот код:где 
   value это номер строки;rail путь до файла;MaxInt это максимальное
   число читаемых строк;все проверил,работает!

||---------------------------------------------------||

```
import java.io.BufferedReader; import java.io.File; 
import java.io.FileNotFoundException; import java.io.FileReader; 
import java.io.IOException;
public class НовыйClass { public static String rail =           
"C://Setting.txt"; public static int MaxInt = 6; public static
String    ReadLocal (int value) throws FileNotFoundException,
IOException{
       File  Setting = new File(rail);
       FileReader reader = new FileReader(Setting);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
       String b = br.readLine();
       byte i = 0;
       while (i < value-1) {            
       b = br.readLine();
       i++;
           if (i-1 == value-1) {
       return b;
           }
       }
       br.close();
       reader.close();
       return b;    }
       //и второй отрывок кода,будет помещать прочтенное в      массив.
       public static void AddArray() throws
       IOException{    String[] OutPut = new String[MaxInt];    for (int i
        = 0; i < MaxInt; i++) {    OutPut[i] = ReadLocal(i);    }    
        System.out.println(OutPut[1]+ "\n" +
                      OutPut[2]+ "\n" +
                      OutPut[3]+ "\n" +
                      OutPut[4]+ "\n" +
                      OutPut[5]+ "\n"); } } '
```

||---------------------------------------------------|| удачи!

Comment: Это помогло,спасибо большое.

Comment: всегда пожалуйста! обращайся